# How to stack photos in Capture One like Aperture?

Tags: capture-one

I'm using Capture One as a substitute for Apple Aperture.
I have watched tutorials and read a lot of documentation and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to stack images as in Aperture.

For those who don't know what Aperture stacks are, there is an explanation [here](https://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=8%26section=1%26tasks=true).

Comment: Google shows me a lot of references to stacking within Capture One, at least when using presets and variants.  For example this: http://help.phaseone.com/en/CO7/Editing-photos/Styles-Presets.aspx#item7  Is that what you are after or does this only apply to limited situations?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but is not the same. It seems that is not possibile to do the same in Capture One. It is possibile to stack variants of the same image but not different images.

Comment: Just as a side note: [Lightroom](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/grouping-photos-stacks.html) and [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/2012/09/grouping/) can do this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (and I work with Capture One for around two years now), there is no way to stack random images. This stands true even with Capture One 11.

However, it is possible with [Variants:](https://imagealchemist.net/capture-one-variants/)

[image]

<sub>Stolen from the above linked blog entry on the Image Alchemist</sub>

Variants are Capture One's version of [Lightroom's Virtual Copies](https://digital-photography-school.com/working-with-virtual-copies-in-lightroom/) - they are copies of a file's recipe. You can collapse them and arrange them as you like. However, this of course is no substitute to stacking various pictures.